# phonegap jquerymobile : how to open external links via Android Browser

Tags: android, cordova

I am working on a project with PhoneGap and JqueryMobile in Android.
Now I need to open an external link via the Android Browser.
I just write

```
window.location.href("http://stackoverflow.com")
```

or

```
window.open("http://stackoverflow.com")
```

The App didn't reply at all?
Please tell me why and help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use `navigator.app.loadUrl('http://stackoverflow.com');`

**EDIT**
Some code for PhoneGap always needs to be device-specific. What I do rather than device check is load a "platform" JS file which has code for each feature that has platform-specific code.

So you can create a function called openUrl which you define in each (Android, iOS, etc) project. In your index.html you just load the platform.js file using a relative path.
The implementation can then be platform-specific without ugly device checking.

Comment: This works for me on Android, I have to use window.open(url) on iOS though, meaning hacky device checking.. if (device.platform.indexOf("droid") > -1) etc.

Answer (score 1):

Comment in phonegap config "res/xml/config.xml"

`<access origin=".*" browserOnly="true"/>`

by

```
<!--<access origin="*" browserOnly="true"/>-->
```

If you allow access, you allow website to be viewed in webview (in this case ALL website).
With no access, all external link are open in native browser.

Comment: This Answer is invalid as this will block all access to remote link required for your app to function.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
window.open('http://www.myurl.nl', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```